# Make anonymous object from unknown xml

Tags: c#, xml, anonymous-types

I want to try and return an object from an XML reader that I wrote to process a file that will have a partially unknown structure.

Here is a sample of the XML.

```
<xml>
  <strings>
    <Home>
      <Index>
        <PreWrapper>
          <Left>
            <Title>Blah</Title>
            <Body>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consec tetuer adipiscing elit. Praesent vestibulum molestie lacus. Aenean nonummy hendrerit mauris. Phasellus porta. Fusce suscipit</Body>
            <LinkText>read more</LinkText>
            <LinkUrl>#</LinkUrl>
          </Left>
          <Center>
            <Title>Exploit your ideas</Title>
            <Body>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consec tetuer adipiscing elit. Praesent vestibulum molestie lacus. Aenean nonummy hendrerit mauris. Phasellus porta. Fusce suscipit</Body>
            <LinkText>read more</LinkText>
            <LinkUrl>#</LinkUrl>
          </Center>
          <Right>
            <Title>Grow your business</Title>
            <Body>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consec tetuer adipiscing elit. Praesent vestibulum molestie lacus. Aenean nonummy hendrerit mauris. Phasellus porta. Fusce suscipit</Body>
            <LinkText>read more</LinkText>
            <LinkUrl>#</LinkUrl>
          </Right>
        </PreWrapper>
      </Index>
    </Home>
  </strings>
  <config>
    <Home>
      <Index>
        <ShowPreWrapper>True</ShowPreWrapper>
      </Index>
    </Home>
  </config>
</xml>
```

I want to be able to just call with my reader

```
var left = reader.GetObject("xml/strings/Home/Index/PreWrapper/Left");
```

and I want it to return an anonymous object (or a dynamic object, but I don't know much about those) that looks like

```
left.Title
left.Body
left.LinkText
left.LinkUrl
```

or

```
var xml = reader.GetObjcet("xml");
```

and be able to dive right into it like

```
xml.strings.Home.Index....
```

but I just cannot figure out how to create this object.
Is this even possible?

Comment: What is unknown about the structure of the XML?

Comment: I could add another node under `Index` called `slideshow` or I might add a `pictureUrl` string in each of the prewrapper sections

Comment: but will you ever get these items, or are the 4 tags (Title, Body, LinkTest, LinkUrl) all you care about?

Comment: this will be passed to cshtml, so I could make changes on the fly is needed.

Comment: Are you happy with them all coming back as strings or List<String>. Trying for List<dynamic> is possible, but messy to the point of not worth bothering with in C# without an xsd

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that you could approximate this using the [`ExpandoObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx) class, but it is quite likely that there are better ways to do it (like using a more loosely typed language, using dictionaries, etc.)

There is certainly nothing built in to the .NET BCL to do this.

**EDIT**: I found this recently, and it probably applies in this situation: [`ElasticObject`](https://github.com/amazedsaint/ElasticObject#readme).

Comment: ExpandoObject looked like it could work, but I think the consensus it that there is no way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this, since C# is a strong-typed language. Maybe it's possible somehow using dynamic C#, but I don't know much about it. But as a solution, you can parse your XML into dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with LINQ to XML If you know for certain an element or attribute name. For this example, you know there will be the `Left` element.

Using this LINQ statement

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Load("c:\\tmp\\test.xml");
var left = from i in document.Descendants("Left") 
           select new { Title = i.Element("Title").Value, 
                        Body = i.Element("Body").Value,
                        LinkText = i.Element("LinkText").Value, 
                        LinkUrl = i.Element("LinkUrl").Value
                      };
```

Now you could do this, as described in your question:

```
Left.Title
Left.Body
Left.LinkText
Left.LinkUrl
```

If you do not know how many elements are descendants of `Left` element, you could do this:

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Load("c:\\tmp\\test.xml");
var left = from i in document.Descendants("Left")
           select new { values = i.Elements().ToList() };
```

This gives an enumerable of a list called `values`. Each item in the list has a `Name` and `Value` property so you can check what it is.

An example of printing all of the values from the first item in the enumerable:

```
foreach (var s in left.First().values)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} has a value of {1}", s.Name, s.Value));            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Build something like that some month ago, have a look and tell me what you think:

[Objects to XML and back to Dynamics](https://gist.github.com/esskar/5358547)

(I hope I added everything).

Comment: I'm sorry, but I cannot compile it. Maybe something missing. And we need at least an example of use. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you use C# 4.0 you can use the dynamic type to achieve this.

To implement your own dynamic behavior just write a class that inherits from [`DynamicObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd487439.aspx) and override [TryGetMember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.trygetmember.aspx):

```
public sealed class DynamicXml : DynamicObject
{
    private XElement _xml;

    private DynamicXml(XElement xml)
    {
        _xml = xml;
    }

    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        XElement xml = _xml.Element(binder.Name);
        if (xml == null)
        {
            result = null;
            return false;
        }

        result = new DynamicXml(xml);

        return true;
    }

    public static implicit operator XElement(DynamicXml xml)
    {
        return xml._xml;
    }

    public static explicit operator DynamicXml(XElement xml)
    {
        return new DynamicXml(xml);
    }
}
```

I added an implicit conversion from `DynamicXml` to `XElement` and an explicit conversion from `XElement` to `DynamicXml`. This way you can easily switch between dynamic and static:

```
XElement root = XDocument.Load("Test.xml").Element("xml");

dynamic xml = (DynamicXml)root;
XElement indexElement = xml.strings.Home.Index;
```

---

UPDATE:

If you want to access attributes you could implement this as an indexed property:

```
public override bool TryGetIndex(GetIndexBinder binder, object[] indexes, out object result)
{
    if (indexes.Length != 1 || !(indexes[0] is string))
    {
        result = null;
        return false;
    }

    result = _xml.Attribute(indexes[0] as string);

    return result != null;
}
```

`var attr = xml.strings.Home.Index["id"]` now returns the `id` attribute of the first `Index` element.

Also you could use the syntax of a method call with no arguments to return all elements instead of only the first one:

```
public override bool TryInvokeMember(InvokeMemberBinder binder, object[] args, out object result)
{
    if (args.Length != 0)
    {
        result = null;
        return false;
    }

    result = _xml.Elements(binder.Name);

    return true;
}
```

`var indexes = xml.strings.Home.Index()` returns an `IEnumerable<XElement>`. Since you can't use dynamic in LINQ expressions or lambdas it would not make a lot of sense to return `IEnumerable<DynamicXml>`.

Comment: Thanks, ill see if I can use this.